# How can I reference CSS (that was compiled from SCSS) from within an IFrame in Angular 5.2?

Tags: html, css, angular, iframe, sass

I am trying to reference a CSS file in my parent application from within an IFrame (I control both the application and the Iframe). My stylesheets are written in SCSS and then appear to be compiled to CSS and written into the HTML as in-line `style` elements in my document's `<header>` when I execute `ng serve`.

What is the correct way to access the CSS from within an IFrame? My first thought is to change the process to output actual CSS files rather writing the CSS in-line, but I'm not sure how that is configured. Perhaps I need to bring in a build tool like Gulp to handle this for me and take it out of angular's hands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inside of and the outside of the iframe are (for most intents and purposes) separate environments. CSS applied to one does not affect the rendering of the other.

Since the inside of the iframe is another page, you'd apply the CSS to that page as you would to any page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand they are seperate environments, but I would like my iframe to link to a style sheet that the parent application owns so that I don't have to maintain the same styles twice (for things like `<table>`s). Maybe the common SCSS should be in it's own artifact that the main app and the iframe app both compile and inject themselves?

Comment: @Sammaron I'm not entirely clear why most of your CSS (or SCSS as the case may be) isn't already separate from the page code as is the usual practice. Regardless, yes, you should break the bulk of the CSS out as its own artifact and then include it by reference in each page.

Comment: hmmm. I am definitely not totally up to speed on my best practices in this area, but [we have a project structure a lot like this](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7) which seems to imply packaging the SCSS in it's own folders but still in within the same repo as the code isn't that weird.

Comment: @Sammaron That looks correct, and the SCSS should end up compiled to its own file(s). Those, in turn should be included in each page that needs them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we decided to go with is to manually compile the SCSS and reference the CSS output from the IFrame. Eventually, this step should be automated (with something like Grunt or Gulp), but for now we are just doing this manually.

Any better solutions are welcome!